# jdeveloper 11g - how to enable autocomplete for primefaces

Tags: primefaces, ide, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I am using JDeveloper 11g with primefaces v 4.0 added as a lib to my project. I don't see any autocomplete on click of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which is a big help for developers. What options have it got to fix this ?
Please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding `Primefaces` to `Jdeveloper 11g` you must add `primefacess.jar` to

```
"project properties->FaceletS Tag Libraries"
```

and select

`"Show Tag Libraries in Palette"` for showing `primefaces` component in `'Component Palette'`

yavari.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the jar files of the primefaces tags in the project properties->Libraries and classpath?

Comment: It does not work even after adding the primefaces libraries to the properties->libraries and classpath

Comment: No. it doesnt. But it works if i add the lib into properties->Facelets Tag Libraries.